# Creating merchant application using Identity API for Paypal

Tags: paypal, no-response

I am trying to create an application for merchants using the below API.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/identity/v1

Not able to create that passed the required parameters. I have payer_id id which I am getting in the response of **/v1/identity/oauth2/userinfo**. I get that special permissions from Paypal.

Here is my request body

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.paypal.com/v1/identity/applications \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ------------------------" \
-d '{
  "application_type": "not cleared what need to add here",  
  "redirect_uris": [
    "return  url"
  ],
  "client_name": "Avtar Singh",
  "contacts": [
    "-------"
  ],
  "payer_id": "-------------",
  "migrated_app": "not cleared what need to add here"
}'
```

Comment: Well what is the response? And what permissions do you have to actually use this?

Comment: Nothing.
For this request as we need to add **payer_id**. For that need some permissions which I have.                                                                      
                                                                                                         
**The end user's external PayPal account ID. Returned only if the access_token has the https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalattributes scope.** Mentioned in PayPal doc [link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/identity/v1/#userinfo)

Comment: Okay well with no permissions to use this, you can't use it. There's no documentation of it anywhere other than this API reference.